# Connecting to site using SharePoint Designer gives - 'There is no web named' error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

When I try connecting to a SharePoint site from the SharePoint Designer come across the error - `There is no web named.` as shown below.

[image]

If I try connecting to another site it works fine.

Comment: Can you share a screen where you enter your site name? Also can you confirm you can browse the site ..

Comment: yes i can browse the site the first screen where i shared is one. and the second screen is where i get error message while i am trying to connect through sharepoint designer am not able to share one more screen shot where i have been asked for username and pwd

Comment: Do you have access to use SharePoint Designer, what permission do you have ?

Comment: i am using the same account for the backup site its working but not in production site does it affect if i use the same account for user profile synchronization in live server?

Comment: here is log which i found in the logs  w3wp.exe (0xA6C0)                        0x8D54 SharePoint Foundation          General                       EventID- aigv4 High     #50004: There is no Web named "". da893d9d-19a8-9065-ac45-2bfca3477402

Comment: Does your farm have a domain top level site collection?
I.e. one at http://yourDomain
Not just http://yourDomain/sites/somesite

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary fix by performing a full crawl on the production search.

Steps are

1. go to service application
2. Select `ProdSearchService` in that
3. Go to `Content Sources`
4. There we can see SharePoint sites in drop down, we can select `Full Crawl`

But whenever I restart the IIS I am again facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command in SharePoint online PowerShell:

```
Set-SPOsite <sharepointsiteURL> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```